# Pygame Window Freezes after starting game_loop()

Tags: python, pygame

Hey Its Max I am having a problem, my `game_loop()` runs for about half a second then freezes, it doesn't say not responding or anything just is completely unresponsive to all buttons, anyone know what i have done wrong? I am defining `game_intro()` and saying that if I click enter `[RETURN]` start `game_loop()` and `intro=False`.

ANY HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED :)

```
def game_loop():
global bot_x1
global bot_x2
global bot_y1
global bot_y2
global x
global y  
global running
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
pygame.display.update()

if running:
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            #CLOSE
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

                  #MOVEMENT

##                if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
##                    x-= selfspeed
##                     
##                if keys [pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 710 :
##                    x+= selfspeed
##
##                if keys [pygame.K_UP] and y > 0:
##                    y-= selfspeed
##
##                if keys [pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 400:
##                    y+= selfspeed

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and x > 0:
                    x-=selfspeed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and x < 710 :
                    x+=selfspeed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and y > 0:
                    y-=selfspeed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and y < 400 :
                    y+=selfspeed

#BOT MOVEMENT
            if bot_y2 > window_height:
                bot_y2 = 0
                bot_x2 = random.uniform(50,750) 

            if bot_y1 > window_height:
                bot_y1 = 0
                bot_x1 = random.uniform(50,750)                    

#SHOW PICTURES
    bot_y1+=botspeed
    bot_y2+=botspeed             
    window.fill(grey)
    bot_1(bot_x1,bot_y1)
    bot_2(bot_x2,bot_y2)
    plane(x,y)
    print("working")
    running=True

#UPDATE GAME DISPLAY+FPS
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

#GAME LOOP BROKEN CLOSE
game_intro()
game_loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

My rep is not high enough to comment yet but there are quite a few details that you are not clarifying enough, for example what the `game_intro()` function does or if the window closes after freezing. You also reference a variable in your explanation that is never shown in the code (`intro = False`). But based on the code you provided, it looks like you never put the `game_loop()` in an actual loop. Instead of...

```
...
if running:
     pygame.display.update()
...
```

inside your `game_loop()` try this instead

```
...
while running:
     pygame.display.update()
....
```

If that still doesn't work please try to provide more code with either an updated question or a pastebin link.